# Docusign "Invalid Grant" error in python flask while sending envelope

Tags: python, flask, docusignapi

```
DocuSign Exception!
   Reason: Bad Request
   Error response: {"error":"invalid_grant"}

Done.
```

I have used this Git Repo "https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-python-jwt".

And added all the details to ds_config.ini file including Private Key with

"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

tknqt07e9/FMiQOKisVsAggZXFEKkXbdoK33i6d/WCX6GrsDIRu+/I0a1UarIRvU

-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
"
Like this

But still getting this error.

Comment: did you obtain consent for your user? and specified the userID (GUID) for that user ?

Comment: Per the linked example, it looks like you shouldn't surround the key in quotes, and you need to put a space in front of the second line and all subsequent lines in the private key. If you try it like that does it work?